# Meaning of the $\mathbb{C}$-linearization of a group action.

Tags: representation-theory

Consider the action of $G=\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}\cong\langle g\rangle$ on the set $A=\{0,1,2\}$ given by $g^k(a)=a+k\bmod3$. Consider the $\mathbb{C}$-linearization of this action. List the irreducible representations which occur as submodules of this representation and the multiplicities with which they occur.

---

I am stuck trying to understand how to approach this problem. First, what does “$\mathbb{C}$-linearization” mean in this context? I’m assuming it is talking about a linear representation $\varphi \colon G\to\mathrm{GL}(\mathbb{C})$ where $\mathbb{C}$ is a 1-dimensional vector space over itself, or equivalently $\varphi:G\to\mathrm{GL}_1(\mathbb{C})\cong\mathbb{C}^\times$. Is this correct? Would this be $\varphi(g)=\zeta_3$, where $\zeta_3$ is some primitive $3$rd root of unity?

If I try to think of $A$ as an abelian group, then this action does not act as automorphisms (since e.g., $g\cdot 0 =1\neq0$), so $A$ is not a $G$-module. Thus, this action does not seem to make a $\mathbb{Z} G$-module, which is what I thought might be useful in decomposing. Is there some way to make this into a $\mathbb{C}G$-module?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez This is a question from a class I did not take but was given the material to review, hence I was given no definition specifically for linearization beyond this question. However, the class textbook is Dummit&Foote, so I am assuming it is a reference to a _linear representation_: a homomorphism from $G\to GL(V)$. I'm assuming "$\mathbb{C}$-linearization" means $V=\mathbb{C}$ here. Other problems specifically state $\mathbb{C}$-representation, which seems more clear, but may be something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a group $G$ acts on a set $X$, then one can construct a complex representation of $G$ as follows. Let $V$ be the vector space that has $X$ as a basis — its elements are formal linear combinations of elements of $X$ with complex coefficients, and the set $X$ is a basis of $V$. Next, let $\rho:G\to GL(V)$ be the unique map such that for each $g\in G$ the linear function $\rho(g):V\to V$ maps each $x$ in $X$ to $gx$.

This representation is the linearization of $X$.

I suggest you do this construction with the specific action you were given, and thus build a represenation of your group. Now you can solve the rest of the problem in exactly the same way as you would with any other representation.

Comment: I see - this is the linearization of the _action_, rather than the linear representation of $G$.

Comment: @J-anon In this context, representation is short for linear representation (i.e. the codomain is a group of linear operators). It is *$^*$a$^*$* linear representation, there is no unique rep we call "the" linear representation. (Perhaps you are thinking of the trivial reprepresentation.)